# Forms authentication login using stored windows credentials rather than current user

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, authentication

I have an asp.net site which authenticates users based on their current windows login as shown below

```
WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(username, false, Session.Timeout);
    string sEncTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    string redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(username, false);
```

This works perfectly fine unless a different username/password combination has been stored in the local system's credential vault, at which time it is the stored credential that gets passed as the login credential.

Making this more difficult, if I try to debug in VS with a stored credential saved, then correctly the current logged in username is passed.

Has anyone come across this before & if so how can I either

1. Write the login code in such a way that it will never look at the credential vault or
2. Configure IIS in such a way as to ignore the credential valut

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use Windows Authentication instead of Forms?

Comment: Apologies Kane for the late reply - requirements are that end user has the option of either forms or windows authentication